# Create an alias using Command, Option, Control, or Fn key as part of the input

Tags: terminal, alias

How can we map these keys into part of an alias or custom shortcut within the terminal? Is it the key codes that must be used or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Keyboard` and set key combinations to *send* commands to the terminal, just click `+` to create a new one.